# Difference between heat emited from resistor and power on the resistor emited to heat

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

Consider a simple electric circuit.

I just not understand what is the difference between heat emited from resistor and power that is on the resistor that emited to heat

why one is $p=I^2R$
and the second is $U=\int I^2Rdt$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation is the rate at which energy is dissipated in the resistor in watts = Joules/sec. The second equation is the total energy dissipated in the resistor in joules after time $t$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ohh, so it's like place and speed analogy?

Comment: Yes in a way. Place, or total distance traveled is the integral of velocity with respect to time as total energy is the integral of power with respect to time.